# Hp spectre x360 Mute mic button not working & LED indicators not lighting up on volume buttons

Tags: keyboard, hp, volume-control, shortcut-keys, media-buttons

I'm currently using pop_os 20.04 LTS on my hp spectre x360.

My mic mute button does not work even though all other audio buttons do. Also all audio buttons which have an LED indicator(mic mute and volume mute) do not light up, but my CAPS lock LED does.

I'm a bit new to linux so not totally familiar with how keys are binded or mapped.

Here is the output of `xev` when I press volume mute, volume up then mic mute:

```
FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  101 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

MappingNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 248

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
    root 0x5c5, subw 0x0, time 3145028, (165,-19), root:(265,145),
    state 0x0, keycode 248 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
    root 0x5c5, subw 0x0, time 3145028, (165,-19), root:(265,145),
    state 0x0, keycode 248 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Also the output from `acpi_listen` for pressing the same sequence of keys:

```
button/mute MUTE 00000080 00000000 K
button/volumeup VOLUP 00000080 00000000 K
 95F24279-4D7B- 00000080 00000000
```

output from `sudo showkey -k` for pressing the same sequence of keys:

```
keycode 113 press
keycode 113 release
keycode 115 press
keycode 115 release
keycode 240 press
keycode 240 release
```

output from `xmodmap -pke | grep Audio` :

```
keycode 121 = XF86AudioMute NoSymbol XF86AudioMute
keycode 122 = XF86AudioLowerVolume NoSymbol XF86AudioLowerVolume
keycode 123 = XF86AudioRaiseVolume NoSymbol XF86AudioRaiseVolume
keycode 171 = XF86AudioNext NoSymbol XF86AudioNext
keycode 172 = XF86AudioPlay XF86AudioPause XF86AudioPlay XF86AudioPause
keycode 173 = XF86AudioPrev NoSymbol XF86AudioPrev
keycode 174 = XF86AudioStop XF86Eject XF86AudioStop XF86Eject
keycode 175 = XF86AudioRecord NoSymbol XF86AudioRecord
keycode 176 = XF86AudioRewind NoSymbol XF86AudioRewind
keycode 198 = XF86AudioMicMute NoSymbol XF86AudioMicMute
keycode 208 = XF86AudioPlay NoSymbol XF86AudioPlay
keycode 209 = XF86AudioPause NoSymbol XF86AudioPause
keycode 215 = XF86AudioPlay NoSymbol XF86AudioPlay
keycode 216 = XF86AudioForward NoSymbol XF86AudioForward
keycode 221 = XF86AudioPreset NoSymbol XF86AudioPreset
keycode 234 = XF86AudioMedia NoSymbol XF86AudioMedia
```

I have already tried:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-mute
```

Any ideas what's causing this ?

Also, how come the keycode from `sudo showkey -k`  are different from the ouptut of `xmodmap`  and `xev`?